# GCC does not see function introduced from base class as ambiguous

Tags: c++, inheritance, overload-resolution, default-arguments, using-declaration

The following code

```
struct Foo{};
struct Bar{};

struct Base {
    Foo func1(const Foo , const Bar = Bar{}) const {
        return {};
    };
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    using Base::func1;
    Foo func1(const Foo ) const {
        return {};
    };
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Derived der;
    der.func1(foo);
}
```

is rejected by ICX and clang, but accepted by GCC (up to 13.1). https://godbolt.org/z/4M3rrs3r4

I think GCC is wrong here. If the two `func1`s were non-members, GCC would reject the call as ambiguous.

Am I right?

Comment: looks like a gcc bug to me.  the derived function is allowed to hide the base one, but only if: *the derived class already has a member with the same name, parameter list, and qualifications* ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration))

Comment: I see it the other way. Because `Base::func1` and `Derived::func1` have different parameter list, there's no hiding but just overriding. `der.func1(foo)` matches the signature of  `Derived::func1` better than `Base::func1`. This match is better than using the (default) second parameter of `Base::func1`. So, there's no ambiguous call and GCC is right.

Comment: @Ripi2 They are both viable and match exactly (defaulted parameters are not considered during overload resolution). If you replace the using-declaration with an overload it also fails to compile on GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/EYfasr7G5

Comment: @Artyer THX. Then it's about how GCC considers the "using-declaration", forgetting overload resolution.

Comment: @Ripi2 Right, they don't match so the base function is included, which it should be.  The issue with that is both can be called with `der.func1(foo);` since the second parameter of the base function is defaulted.  Clang gets that right, GCC doesn't

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug of the compiler **gcc**.

From the C++ 20 (9.9 The using declaration)

> 15 [*Note 6* : **For the purpose of forming a set of candidates during
> overload resolution, the functions that are introduced by a
> using-declaration into a derived class are treated as though they were
> members of the derived class** (11.8). In particular, the implicit
> object parameter is treated as if it were a reference to the derived
> class rather than to the base class (12.4.2). This has no effect on
> the type of the function, and in all other respects the function
> remains a member of the base class. — *end note*]

and (9.3.4.7 Default arguments)

> 9. ... When a declaration of a function is introduced by way of a using-declaration (9.9), any default argument information associated
>    with the declaration is made known as well.

So for the overload resolution the set of function candidates in the class `Derived` consists of two functions

```
Foo func1(const Foo , const Bar = Bar{}) const {
    return {};
}
```

and

```
Foo func1(const Foo ) const {
    return {};
}
```

And such a call

```
der.func1(foo);
```

in this case is ambiguous. Either function can be called.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug that was introduced with GCC 7: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82894